# Build.VERSION_CODES.GINGERBREAD shows error

Tags: android, sdk

I am very confuse because `Build.VERSION_CODES.GINGERBREAD` line shows error in my code but `Build.VERSION_CODES.ECLAIR` is perfectly run. What is problem please tell me...

Here is the code.

```
if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.GINGERBREAD) {//Show error in this line
    lv.setOverScrollMode(ListView.OVER_SCROLL_NEVER);
}
```

But nothing wrong with

```
if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.ECLAIR) {//nothing wrong
    lv.setOverScrollMode(ListView.OVER_SCROLL_NEVER);
}
```

What should I do ?

Comment: code does not compile.

Comment: set `android:minSdkVersion="10"` and `android:targetSdkVersion="21"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[GINGERBREAD](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Build.VERSION_CODES.html#GINGERBREAD) is Android 2.3, and [ECLAIR](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Build.VERSION_CODES.html#ECLAIR) is Android 2. Here the constant [GINGERBREAD](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Build.VERSION_CODES.html#GINGERBREAD) was not introduced while Android 2.

If you set your *build target* to below of [GINGERBREAD](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Build.VERSION_CODES.html#GINGERBREAD), it will show you an error, because compiler can not find that constant, above the *build target*.

Android always suggest to use latest build of Android, that is [LOLLIPOP](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Build.VERSION_CODES.html#LOLLIPOP)

---

From [***Creating an Android Project***](http://developer.android.com/tools/projects/projects-eclipse.html#CreatingAProject)

- Select a **Compile With** API version. This setting specifies what version of the SDK to compile your project against. We strongly recommend using the most recent version of the API.